# Cypress/Next.js E2E test with --watch option works well, but failed with --headless

Tags: next.js, cypress, e2e-testing, headless

Thanks for the cypress team.
I have one issue with e2e headless test on command.

When I run the test with --watch option, it passes well.
But it is failed for the --headless option.
I need to run this on CI, so it has to resolve this issues soon.

Here are commands that I run.

`yarn nx run checkout-e2e:e2e --watch`

`yarn nx run checkout-e2e:e2e --headless`

I have 3 test files totally, and the specific thing is that the first test doesn't pass after long time delay(around 60 sec) but the rest ones pass.

Here is one code file to run.
The other files are almost same.

```
const classname = 'buybox--buy-box-example-one-size'
const url = `?path=/story/${classname}`

describe('BuyBox Example visual regression', () => {
  it('Matches the snapshot', () => {
    cy.visit(url)
    cy.viewport(1000, 1500)
    cy.get(`#${classname}`)
    cy.get('body').type('S')
    cy.get('body').type('A')
    cy.wait(3000)
    cy.get('body').matchImageSnapshot('buyboxOneSizeDesktopExample')
    cy.viewport(375, 667)
    cy.get(`#${classname}`)
    cy.get('body').type('S')
    cy.get('body').type('A')
    cy.wait(5000)
    cy.get('body').matchImageSnapshot('buyboxOneSizeExample')
  })
})
```

My Dev Env:

- Windows 10
- VS code
- Cypress 6.0.1
- Node 14.16.1
- Storybook 6.2.8

Here is the error screenshot in headless mode.
https://prnt.sc/131k32j

Please reply if anyone knows its reason and solution.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried to solve this issue and found it finally.

Go to plugin/index.js and comment this line...

```
 // on('file:preprocessor', preprocessTypescript(config))
```

[Fixing e2e test failed on headless mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YFMgK.png)

I am not sure why this works for me but I hope that this will be helped for everyone who has same issue.
If anyone knows the reason of this solution, comment here please.
Thanks.